# Laravel 7 Socialite ORCID package 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: laravel-7, laravel-socialite

Using Laravel 7, and [this](https://github.com/SocialiteProviders/Documentation/blob/master/docs/providers/orcid.md) package I tried to create an oath using an orcid socialite registration using a simple link.

DOCUMENTATION ("How does “3 legged OAuth” work?"):
https://info.orcid.org/documentation/integration-and-api-faq/#easy-faq-2537

```
 <a href="login/orcid" class="btn btn-primary">Login Using Orcid</a>
```

When the user clicks the button, a redirection occurs, but when the redirection occurs the system does not allow the user to "Grand" or "Deny" the connection to the service. Instead, a blank page redirects the user back to my project.

During the whole process, I can see that the URL changes, to Orchid.org/[etc][client_id] so I think a connection is established with Orcid.

But then I get a URL `orcid/callback#error=invalid_scope`
And an error message:

> Server error: `POST https://orcid.org/oauth/token` resulted in a `500 Internal Server Error` response: {"error":"server_error","error_description":"An authorization code must be supplied."}

Did I miss something?

my .env variables

```
ORCID_CLIENT_ID=XXX
ORCID_CLIENT_SECRET=XXX
ORCID_REDIRECT_URL=https://WEE/login/orcid/callback
ORCID_ENVIRONMENT=production
```

My LoginController functions for my routes:

```
 public function orchidLogin(){

        return Socialite::driver('orcid')->redirect();
    }

    public function handleOrcidCallback(Request $request){

        //How do I get the data for registration???

    }
```

My routes:

```
Route::get('login/orcid', 'Auth\LoginController@orchidLogin');
Route::get('login/orcid/callback', 'Auth\LoginController@handleOrcidCallback');
```

Answer (score 1):

I dug deep in the mentioned [package](https://github.com/SocialiteProviders/Documentation/blob/master/docs/providers/orcid.md) found that the package by default assume scopes in `vendor\socialite\orcid\provider` which was:

```
protected $scopes = ['/authenticate','/read-limited'];
```

If you only registered for public API then the scope `'/read-limited'` not available for you. That's why you get the error `#error=invalid_scope` and as per ORCID documentation [Here](https://info.orcid.org/documentation/integration-guide/troubleshooting/#easy-faq-2569) the scope `/read-limited` (for Member API only).

So to fix the issue you have 2 options:

1. Register for member API.
2. ***or*** assign public API scopes only.

   For example:

   ```
   Socialite::driver('orcid')->scopes(['/authenticate','openid'])->redirect()
   ```